# read file from prompt

Tags: assembly, io, mips, mars-simulator

I have a poblem, I want to read from file and print out text word by word. When I state the FILENAME to "testtext.txt"(the file I actually have) the programm works fine. But in this case, when I try to type in the file name and save it to FILENAME adress, programm does not work. The descriptor is -1 and it stops working. What I did wrong here? Can you help me identify the mistake here, please?

```
   .data
    FILENAME:   .ascii ""
    CHARBUFFER: .byte  0,0
    DELIMITERS: .byte  32,44,46
    string: .space 1024
    .text
                j main

    read_delimit:

    li $v0 13
    move $a0 $s1
    li $a1 0
    li $a2 0
    syscall
    move $s2 $v0
    blt $s2 0 err

li $v0 14
move $a0 $s2
la $a1 CHARBUFFER
li $a2 1024
syscall
move $s3 $v0

loop:

    lb $t5 0($a1)
    beq $t5 $t0 space
    beq $t5 $t1 comma
    beq $t5 $t2 end

    li $v0 11
    move $a0 $t5
    syscall

    addi $a1 $a1 1

    j loop

space:

    li $v0 11
    move $a0 $t6
    syscall

    addi $a1 $a1 1
    j loop

comma:
    li $v0 11
    move $a0 $t5
    syscall

    li $v0 11
    move $a0 $t6
    syscall

    addi $a1 $a1 1
    addi $a1 $a1 1
    j loop

end:
    li $v0 0
            jr $ra
err:
    li $v0 -1 
    jr $ra


main:                     
    la $s0 DELIMITERS
    lbu $t0 0($s0)          #space
    lbu $t1 1($s0)          #coma
    lbu $t2 2($s0)          #full stop

li      $v0, 8
    la      $a0, FILENAME
    li      $a1, 64
    syscall

    li $v0 4
    la $a0 FILENAME
    syscall

    la $s1 FILENAME

li $t6 012          #new_line

jal read_delimit
```

Comment: `.ascii ""` doesn't reserve space for any characters. You should use something like `.space 100` instead (or however many characters to plan to store).

Comment: I tried '.space' 64 but it doesn't work eiher

Comment: You are using registers `$t0`, `$t1` and `$t2` for comparisons, without having initialized them first. Then again, you should not use those registers for storing values, because they are not preserved during syscalls. Also, you really should comment your code, especially if you want others to help you.